# How set constraints on generic param of generic class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say I have such interface:

```
interface Identity<TValue> {
  readonly value: TValue;
}
```

And now I want to create storage for then

```
class IdentityStorage<TIdentity> {

}
```

But I want to set type constraint for `TIdentity` type. How can i do it? I've tried something like this

```
class IdentityStorage<TIdentity extends Identity> {} 
class IdentityStorage<TIdentity<TValue> extends Identity<TValue>> {}
```

But none of them works. How can i set such constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use two type parameters, as in:

```
class IdentityStorage<TValue, TIdentity extends Identity<TValue>> {}
```

This represents the exact constraint you want.  If you're willing to be a bit looser with your constraint, you could do something like

```
class IdentityStorage<TIdentity extends Identity<any>> {}
```

which will also work but might allow some things you don't want (depending on how many properties in `Identity<TValue>` depend on `TValue` and in what way... as stated there's just one property of type `TValue`, so this will be fine.)

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Can you think of an instance in which the first version prevents something the second version allows ? Since `TValue` has no constrain it can be `any` anyway, but even if it had a constraint and the same constraint was present in both classes could you do something with the second version that would be prevented by the second ?

Comment: I think if `Identity<T>` were invariant in `T` it would be useful to have both parameters.  For example, imagine it had a getter and a setter of type `T`.  The `any` version would allow the getter and setter to be of different types (and you couldn’t fix it with `unknown` since that makes the setter as narrow as possible).

Comment: Thanks, you very much. Exactly what i need!